How to Include Sensor Value in InfluxDB Check Alert Message Template
I am transferring data from a sensor to InfluxDB. If the read value exceeds a threshold, I want to issue an alert message. I created a check for this purpose. The following status message template (SMT) works without issues:
${r._check_name}:  is ${r._level}


However, I also want to display the sensor value in the alert message. I modified the SMT as follows:
${r._check_name}:  is ${r._level} Its value is ${string(v: r._value)}


The modification doesn't work, and I get the following error in the InfluxDB logs:
2024-06-25 17:05:00 ts=2024-06-25T14:05:00.022814Z lvl=info msg="Error exhausting result iterator" log_id=0p~Xx~O0000 service=task-executor error="runtime error @26:8-26:79: check: failed to evaluate map function: 21:68-21:90: interpolated expression produced a null value" name=wide-to14

How can I modify the message to include the sensor value in the alert?
